# How to tell msys2 cmake to use static libraries

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, static-linking, msys2

Enviroment:

1. Windows 11 x64
2. Msys2 with the mingw64 compiler
3. VSCode
4. CMAKE

I want to compile an executable so that I can give it to another device without having to deal with installing dependencies on that system.

I currently use cmake together with msys2, vscode and the mingw64 compiler. The Problem I am having is that when I currently compile, it seems like cmake only uses the .dll.a files, I installed with pacman, for linking. Thus it will not run on another system. When I try to change the CMakeLists.txt to link with a static library, it give me a linker error for every library I try it on.

The two questions I am having are:

1. How do I get cmake to use the static variant of system libraries like libstdc++.dll
2. How can I use the static library varient of a package I installed with pacman in msys2

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26.4)
project(Project LANGUAGES C CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(Project main.cpp)
#set(CMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE 1)

target_include_directories(Project PUBLIC C:/msys64/usr/include/curl)
target_include_directories(Project PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

find_package(CURL REQUIRED)

#target_link_libraries(Project C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libcurl.a) <-- Does not work, when building it gives me a linker error for every curl function in my project
target_link_libraries(Project ${CURL_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(Project ${OpenSSL_LIBRARIES})
```

I have tried linking only with the commented out link_libraries command and removing the find packaged, however when I try to build it afterwards I get this linker error:

```
[main] Building folder: Proto 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\cmake.EXE --build c:/Users/user/Documents/project/Proto/build --config Debug --target all --verbose -j 10 --
[build] C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\cmake.exe -SC:\Users\user\Documents\project\Proto -BC:\Users\user\Documents\project\Proto\build --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
[build] C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_start C:\Users\user\Documents\project\Proto\build\CMakeFiles C:\Users\user\Documents\project\Proto\build\\CMakeFiles\progress.marks
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 all
[build] mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/user/Documents/project/Proto/build'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f CMakeFiles\Project.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/Project.dir/depend
[build] mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/user/Documents/project/Proto/build'
[build] C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\cmake.exe -E cmake_depends "MinGW Makefiles" C:\Users\user\Documents\project\Proto C:\Users\user\Documents\project\Proto C:\Users\user\Documents\project\Proto\build C:\Users\user\Documents\project\Proto\build C:\Users\user\Documents\project\Proto\build\CMakeFiles\Project.dir\DependInfo.cmake --color=
[build] mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/user/Documents/project/Proto/build'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f CMakeFiles\Project.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/Project.dir/build
[build] mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/user/Documents/project/Proto/build'
[build] [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Project.dir/main.cpp.obj
[build] C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe  @CMakeFiles/Project.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -g -MD -MT CMakeFiles/Project.dir/main.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles\Project.dir\main.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\Project.dir\main.cpp.obj -c C:\Users\user\Documents\project\Proto\main.cpp
[build] [100%] Linking CXX executable Project.exe
[build] C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\cmake.exe -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\Project.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
[build] C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\cmake.exe -E rm -f CMakeFiles\Project.dir/objects.a
[build] C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\ar.exe qc CMakeFiles\Project.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles\Project.dir\objects1.rsp
[build] C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -g -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\Project.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -o Project.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libProject.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles\Project.dir\linkLibs.rsp
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Project.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): in function `tokenRequests(char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*)':
[build] C:/Users/user/Documents/project/Proto/main.cpp:37: undefined reference to `__imp_curl_global_init'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/user/Documents/project/Proto/main.cpp:38: undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_init'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/user/Documents/project/Proto/main.cpp:48: undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_setopt'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/user/Documents/project/Proto/main.cpp:49: undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_setopt'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/user/Documents/project/Proto/main.cpp:50: undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_setopt'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/user/Documents/project/Proto/main.cpp:51: undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_setopt'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/user/Documents/project/Proto/main.cpp:53: undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_perform'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/user/Documents/project/Proto/main.cpp:55: undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_strerror'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/user/Documents/project/Proto/main.cpp:60: undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_cleanup'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/user/Documents/project/Proto/main.cpp:63: undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_cleanup'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Project.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): in function `main':
[build] C:/Users/user/Documents/project/Proto/main.cpp:268: undefined reference to `__imp_curl_global_cleanup'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/user/Documents/project/Proto/main.cpp:275: undefined reference to `__imp_curl_global_cleanup'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/user/Documents/project/Proto/main.cpp:297: undefined reference to `__imp_curl_global_cleanup'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/user/Documents/project/Proto/main.cpp:311: undefined reference to `__imp_curl_global_cleanup'
[build] collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[build] mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Project.dir\build.make:100: Project.exe] Error 1
[build] mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/user/Documents/project/Proto/build'
[build] mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/user/Documents/project/Proto/build'
[build] mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:82: CMakeFiles/Project.dir/all] Error 2
[build] mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:90: all] Error 2
[proc] The command: C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\cmake.EXE --build c:/Users/user/Documents/project/Proto/build --config Debug --target all --verbose -j 10 -- exited with code: 2
[driver] Build completed: 00:00:04.819
[build] Build finished with exit code 2
```

Comment: One Google search, minimal scanning: https://www.reddit.com/r/cmake/comments/hsxwji/statically_linked_executable/ If it's not already duped on this site, someone could probably turn this into a decent answer.

Comment: @sweenish this doesn't answer the part about pacman, i think pacman only installs dynamic libraries, so he'd have to build those libraries from source statically, but i may be wrong, there's also vcpkg that can install static libraries.

Comment: @AhmedAEK Two questions should be **two questions** on SO. That's honestly reason enough to close this one, for lacking focus.

Comment: @AhmedAEK A combination of setting the link options with -static and setting the cmake_flags to what the post said, it leaves me with an executable that still requires libcrypto, libnghttp2 and some others I assume that these are requirements of curl, I'll try and put these into the same directory to see if that helps resolve it

Comment: Every library has its own way for using in static form. Well, in many cases (and with many libraries) it is sufficient to just specify `.a` library instead of `.so`. But on Windows this doesn't work: one should define some macro for make a library's header file to not declare functions as dynamic ones. As for static linking with system libraries (like `libstdc++.dll`), they have own specifics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure that CMake uses libraries with MSYS2 here are a few things you can do;

1. **Linking Static System Libraries**;
   You can force linkage by adding the flag;

```cpp
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS " static libgcc static libstdc++")
```

2. **Static Libraries, with Pacman**;
   When installing libraries using `pacman` make sure you're getting the versions than just the import libraries (`.dll.a` files). The static versions usually have the extension `.a` without the `.dll` prefix. In case you can't find the version through `pacman` consider building the library from source with linkage enabled.
3. **CMakeLists.txt Updates**;
   check that you are linking against the libraries in your CMakeLists.txt file. The `find_package` command should automatically find the libraries if they are available. If not you might need to specify the path to the `file.

Also keep in mind that some libraries have dependencies on libraries. If you're linking statically ensure that all dependencies are also available, as libraries.

I hope these suggestions help!

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say with point 2, I installed libcurl with pacman, I now have a libcurl.a, libcurl.dll and libcurl.dll.a all in the same directory, and while cmake seems to find the dll.a without a problem, once I try to use the .a it fails. It tells me that it couldn't find any reference to the function calls, like it didnt find anything. I'll try 1. and see if that helps.

Comment: When adding set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS " -static libgcc -static libstdc++") it complains about those two libraris not being found

Comment: When linking statically, remember that all dependencies of the main library (in this case, libcurl) must also be available and linked statically. This includes any libraries that libcurl itself depends on.

The error about not finding -static libgcc and -static libstdc++ indicates a possible typo or misconfiguration. You need to ensure that the flags are correctly set, as shown in my answer.